# How can I set up a http2 server in Go 1.8 without third party libraries?

Tags: go

I heard that http2 would be supported in the latest Go versions. How can I put up a http2 server without using `golang.org/x/net/http2`?

In previous versions you could do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/http2"
)

func main() {
    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":443",
        Handler: http.FileServer(http.Dir(cwd)),
    }
    http2.ConfigureServer(srv, &http2.Server{})
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServeTLS("server.crt", "server.key"))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use `net/http` in most instances:

> Starting with Go 1.6, the http package has transparent support for the HTTP/2 protocol when using HTTPS.
>
> The http package's Transport and Server both automatically enable HTTP/2 support for simple configurations. To enable HTTP/2 for more complex configurations, to use lower-level HTTP/2 features, or to use a newer version of Go's http2 package, import "golang.org/x/net/http2" directly and use its ConfigureTransport and/or ConfigureServer functions. Manually configuring HTTP/2 via the golang.org/x/net/http2 package takes precedence over the net/http package's built-in HTTP/2 support.

Comment: If I set up a TLS connection as I would normally do, then http2 is automatically added?

Comment: Btw will this change the procedure to upgrading to Websocket connections in any way? Would I still be able to the gorilla/websocket for example?

Comment: It should automatically do http2, yes.  And no, it shouldn't change the procedure for upgrading to websocket.

Comment: Thanks for the help!